PHPUnit and Laravel responds 401 status code it should return 422
I'm studying Laravel 11 and I have my first problem using PHPStorm (I don't know if it's my test or not).
I have this controller:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
  public function login(Request $request)
  {
    $request->validate([
      'email' => 'email|string',
      'password' => 'required|min:8',
    ]);

    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

    if (!$token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
      return jsonResponse(status: 401, message: 'Unauthorized');
    }

    return jsonResponse(data: [
      'token'      => $token,
      'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
    ]);
  }
}

My test code:
public function test_email_must_be_required(): void
  {
    $credentials = ['password' => 'password'];

    $response = $this->postJson("{$this->apiBase}/login", $credentials);

    $response->assertStatus(422);
    $response->assertJsonStructure(['message', 'data', 'status', 'errors' => ['email']]);
    $response->assertJsonFragment(['errors' => ['email' => ['The email field is required.']]]);
  }

But when I run the test, I have the following response:

However, it should not return 401 because the email in the test credentials is not being sent. It should return response code 422 instead.
[EDIT]
When I change my validate method:
...
   'email' => 'required|email|string',
...

My code response is 200:

[EDIT 2]
This is my routes/api.php code:


Can you share the code for route /login in your route file (web/api)

@skdishansacin sure, I've edited my post to show you that code.

'email' => 'email|string',

This rule checks if the email is a valid email format and is a string. However, the field is not marked as required. Therefore, if no email is provided in the request, the validation will not fail, and the request will proceed to the next step (which is auth()->attempt()), where it eventually returns a 401 Unauthorized response due to missing credentials.

Yesterday I've edited my post to add the "required" condition and the respose was 200.
